# Cross-hub calls in SignalR 2.2.1 - DefaultHubManager gets Hub with null HubCallerContext

Tags: signalr

I'm using SignalR 2.2.1 which is the latest version in NuGet. I am opposed to using `dynamic`, so strong-typing is always preferred.

My project has two "classes" of clients and so there are two Hubs:

- `ChatClient` + `ChatHub : Hub<IChatClient>`, which are clients that exchange chat application messages.
- `AdminClient` + `AdminHub : Hub<IAdminClient>`, which are clients with special administrative powers

Within the `AdminHub` I want to call methods of the `ChatHub`, such as loading a message from a database and broadcasting it to all users of the `ChatHub`:

Here's my logic (abbreviated):

```
public interface IChatClient {

    void ReceiveMessage(String message);
}

public class AdminHub : Hub<IAdminClient> {

    // this method is called from the Admin client
    public void ShowMotdToRandomUser() {

        String message = GetMessageOfTheDayFromDatabase( ... );

        // get the Chat hub:
        DefaultHubManager defaultHubs = new DefaultHubManager( GlobalHost.DependencyResolver );
        ChatHub chatHub = defaultHubs.ResolveHub( "Chat" ) as ChatHub;
        chatHub.Context = this.Context; // because chatHub.Context == null

        chatHub.InternalSendMessageToRandomUser( message );
    }
}


public class ChatHub : Hub<IChatClient> {

    // this is a normal hub method that chat hub clients call
    public void SendMessage(String message) {

        this.Clients.All.ReceiveMessage( message );
    }

    // this is the special method called from AdminHub:
    internal void InternalSendMessageToRandomUser(String message) {

        String connectionId = GetRandomConnectionId( ... ); // the Hub stores all connectionIds from OnConnected to static state
        this.Client( connectionId ).ReceiveMessage( message );
    }
}
```

However this fails in the call to `IChatClient.ReceiveMessage`:

```
NullReferenceException {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}
at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.SignalProxy.Invoke(String method, Object[] args)
at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.TypedClientBuilder.IChatHubClientImpl.ReceiveMessage(String )
at MyProject.ChatHub.InternalSendMessageToRandomUser(String message)
at MyProject.AdminHub.ShowMotdToRandomUser(String message)
at lambda_method(Closure , IHub , Object[] )
at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubMethodDispatcher.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.<WrapVoidAction>b__0(IHub hub, Object[] parameters)
at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubMethodDispatcher.Execute(IHub hub, Object[] parameters)
at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubDispatcher.Incoming(IHubIncomingInvokerContext context)
```

Comment: Have you trying resolving the hub like this: `GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>())` ?

Comment: @Pawel yes - that gives me a HubContext, not a Hub.